# Change iOS Application Target value in XCode4

Tags: iphone, xcode4

I created my App Id in the Apple Dev Portal with lowercase name but I accidentally setup my xcode project with upper case name.

Now when I try to build and target my device (with the mobileprovision file), I get the error that 
com.companyname.AppName doesn't com.companyname.appname.

How can I fix this in XCode4 so it matches the App ID I've setup on the portal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you click on your target(blue icon in top left corner) go under info and you will see what you need to change under Bundle identifier.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the value of the PRODUCT_NAME.

This is set to $TARGET_NAME by default. To change that you need to rename your project. Unfortunately your project name will be lower case in the Navigator.

- Click on your project name (top left)
- Click on the file file view (file icon just above it)
- In the utilities view on the right under "Identity" change "Project Name" to be lower case.

I changed the value of PRODUCT_NAME directly:

- Click on your project in the Navigator
- Click on Build Settings
- Type "product" into the search field
- Double click the "Product Name" setting
- Change the value